# Simple Virtualbox/QEMU style application development

Tags: sdk, virtual-machine, virtualization, qemu

I have been experimenting with kernel building and have successfully created a very basic kernel which I am slowly extending to add features. I have successfully run it in virtualbox and qemu but thought I would investigate the possibility of building a simple virtual machine emulator like those but with just the required features to run my very simple kernel, or better yet, just to be able to boot a machine in software by passing through the host hardware to the guest kernel.

I know that visualization is a very complex topic that has taken huge amounts of effort by a lot of people to get it to the stage it is at with projects like Virtualbox or VMWare and I don't want to try and re-create them.

Alternatively if anyone knows of an existing virtualization sdk that could be used to embed the output of the running virtual machine into another application that could be used. I want to create an application that boots this virtual machine as part of a simulation.

Answer (score 0):

Please find [TVMM](http://web.yl.is.s.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~kaneda/tvmm/), which is an open source educational virtual machine monitor. Its code is somehow simple and you can get many points form it.